# fluxxor add more than 1 set of actions to a flux instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have set up a React application using Fluxxor, I am trying to use a controller view which gets multiple stores and actions, similar to this [carousel example](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/fluxxor/tree/master/examples/carousel).

However in the fluxxor example it uses multiple stores but only the one set of actions. I wanted to know how to pass in multple actions.

```
var React = require('react/addons'),
    Fluxxor = require("fluxxor"),
    authorActions = require("../actions/author-actions"),
    authorStore = require("../stores/author-store"),
    productActions = require("../actions/product-actions"),
    productStore = require("../stores/product-store");

var stores = { ProductStore: new productStore(), AuthorStore: new authorStore()  };
// how do I combine my actions here?
var flux = new Fluxxor.Flux(stores, actions);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fluxxor [supports adding actions dynamically](http://fluxxor.com/documentation/flux.html#-fluxxor-flux-addactions-actions-):

```
var flux = new Fluxxor.Flux(stores);
flux.addActions(authorActions);
flux.addActions(productActions);
```

If the namespaces don't conflict, you can also merge them together with something like [Underscore's extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
var actions = _.extend({}, authorActions, productActions);
```

or `Object.assign` (or a polyfill):

```
var actions = Object.assign({}, authorActions, productActions);
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to @BinaryMuse answer. I like to namespace my actions so there'll be no clashes on any generically named actions.

Just initiate an object with a key for each namespace:

```
...
var actions = { author: authorActions, product: productActions  };
var flux = new Fluxxor.Flux(stores, actions);
```

Then call them with their namespace:

```
this.getFlux().actions.author.add("Aldus", "Huxley", ...);
```